# generic object and function object

Tags: c++, generic-collections

I try to write generic tree. I added function object to compare among the values of the vertices. but I got problem:

the relevant parts of the header file:

```
template <typename  T,typename Func>
```

.....

```
void addData(T dataIn,Func condition){
```

the main:

```
#include "gentree.h"
class compare_int {
public:
    int operator()(int a,int b){
        if (a==b) return 0;
        else    if (a>b) return -1;
        else return 1;

    }
};
using namespace std;

int main() {
    genTree<int,compare_int> new_tr(5);
    new_tr.addData(3,compare_int);
    return 0;
}
```

I get errors for this line:

```
new_tr.addData(3,compare_int);
```

the errors are: 
"expected primary-expression before ')' token" and "invalid arguments '"
any ideas?

Comment: BTW, you probably want `Func` to be in constructor, not in `addData` argument.

Answer (score 1):

In the expression `new_tr.addData(3,compare_int);` 3 is a value, but `compare_int` is a type. You cannot pass a type as a parameter to a function.

You can either create a separate value, or pass a temporary compare object, like

```
new_tr.addData(3,compare_int());
```

Answer (score 0):

You pass type as a parameter instead of object. You have to create an object of the `compare_int` type and pass it like:

```
compare_int comparator;
new_tr.addData(3, comparator);
```